# Convert a double list to a grouped string

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, performance, testing

The program has an input a list of doubles and the output needs to be a string containing the list values grouped by their value. The list values will be grouped if they are equal.
 Something like: 
    input 9,77,5,5,31 => output 9 77 2*5 31

I created an algorithm in C# (in Java I think that is almost the same) for this but I am not sure if it can be improved regarding its speed or code quaility, or if it has some bugs that I could not see. The algorithm having also some more input, output examples is below.

```
          List<double> input = new List<double> { 11, 32, 32, 43}; // output 11 2*32 43
        //List<double> input = new List<double> { 11, 11, 43, 43 }; // output 2*11 2*43
        //List<double> input = new List<double> { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }; // output 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
        //List<double> input = new List<double> { 11, 11, 11, 11, 11 }; // output 5 * 11
        //List<double> input = new List<double> { 11, 11, 32, 22, 22, 22, 4, 10, 10 }; // output 2*11 32 3*22 4 2*10

        string listAsString = string.Empty;
        double nextElem = double.MinValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            double currentElem = input[i];

            if (i + 1 < input.Count)
            {
                nextElem = input[i + 1];
            }

            int equalCount = 0;
            while (currentElem.Equals(nextElem) && i < input.Count)
            {
                equalCount++;
                i++;
                currentElem = nextElem;

                if (i < input.Count)
                {
                    nextElem = input[i];
                }
            }

            if (equalCount < 2)
            {
                listAsString += currentElem + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                listAsString += equalCount + "*" + currentElem + " ";
                i--;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(listAsString);
```

Please let me know if you noticed some bugs or see some improvements that can be done.

Also if you know another implementation of this requirement please add it so that a comparation regarding results, speed, code quality between the algorithms can be done... and find the best way to handle this.

Comment: For 1,3,1 the output is 1 3 1 or 2*1 3?

Comment: This seems more like a question for codereview.se?

Comment: Hi Antonín, for input 1 3 1 output will be 1 3 1 . Only the consecutive equal numbers will be grouped.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for sugestion I will post also there !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the requirement is to group only *consecutive* equal values, the `Dictionary` and LINQ `GroupBy` approaches mentioned in another answer do not apply because they will produce incorrect result for input sequence like `1,2,1`. Also there is no standard LINQ method for doing such grouping (except eventually `Aggregate` method, but it's no more than inefficient `for` / `foreach` loop equivalent).

Shortly, your algorithm is the best for such task. But implementation is not.

The main bottleneck is the string concatenation as mentioned by [Peroxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943126/convert-a-double-list-to-a-grouped-string/40943218#40943218), which (also mentioned in the other answer) is easily fixable by utilizing the `StringBuilder` class. Once you do that, the performance will be just fine.

The other issue I see in the implementation is usage of special values (`double.MinValue`), duplicate corner case checks, decrementing `for` loop variable inside the body etc. So although it probably works and I don't see directly a bug, it's kind of hard to follow the algorithm logic and spot a potential bug just reading the implementation. The algorithm itself is quite simple, I would implement it this way:

```
static string ListAsString(List<double> input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; )
    {
        var value = input[i];
        int count = 1;
        while (++i < input.Count && input[i] == value)
            count++;
        if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(' ');
        if (count > 1) sb.Append(count).Append('*');
        sb.Append(value);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

which IMO is quite easier to follow. Note that there is no duplicate code, no special values and the loop variable `i` advancing is done only in one place inside the outer loop body. Again, this has nothing to do with performance (which is provided by the `StringBuilder` usage), but simply readability, redundancy elimination and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I see great potential with `Dictionary` usage here, here is a quick solution I made with a dictionary implementation:

```
var input = new List<double> { 9, 77, 5, 5, 31 };
var dict = new Dictionary<double, int>();
var listAsString = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in input)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(item))
        dict[item]++;
    else
        dict[item] = 1;
}

foreach (var item in dict)
{
    listAsString.Append(item.Value > 1 ? $"{item.Value}*{item.Key} " : $"{item.Key} ");
}

Console.WriteLine(listAsString);
```

If you ever wanted a non efficient LINQ one liner solution:

```
string result = string.Join(" ", input.GroupBy(i => i)
                                       .Select(x => 
                                       x.Count() > 1 ? 
                                       $"{x.Count()}*{x.Key} " : 
                                       $"{x.Key} "));
```

However, I believe your method is written nicely, albeit a bit less readable than the dictionary one, but the main flaw with your solution is that you are using a string when building the final string, you should definitely be using a `StringBuilder`, I have introduced the `StringBuilder` in your method and made comparisons between these three methods:

```
Dictionary    | Your method | GroupBy method
------------------------------------------------
 2 ms         |    0 ms     |    5 ms           n=3
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=6
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=12
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=24
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=48
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=96
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=192
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=384
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=768
 0 ms         |    0 ms     |    0 ms           n=1536
 1 ms         |    0 ms     |    1 ms           n=3072
 3 ms         |    2 ms     |    3 ms           n=6144
 5 ms         |    4 ms     |    6 ms           n=12288
 8 ms         |    7 ms     |    14 ms          n=24576
 14 ms        |    13 ms    |    25 ms          n=49152
 31 ms        |    32 ms    |    66 ms          n=98304
 80 ms        |    59 ms    |    146 ms         n=196608
 149 ms       |    123 ms   |    294 ms         n=393216
 246 ms       |    218 ms   |    504 ms         n=786432
 483 ms       |    428 ms   |    1040 ms        n=1572864
 999 ms       |    873 ms   |    2070 ms        n=3145728
 1995 ms      |    1784 ms  |    3950 ms        n=6291456
```

Your solution is always the fastest, if you want to go for speed, keep your solution, but change it to use `StringBuilder`, use `listAsString.Append(currentElem + " ")` instead of `listAsString += currentElem + " "`.

`GroupBy` could be used if you will only operate with collections that have `n < 1000`, use the `Dictionary` solution if you would rather settle with readability over speed.

Comment: Your efforts have surely made this useful for me. Was playing around with the linq before you eventually added it to your answer. .Net Fiddle ran our of memory for anything above 1mil.

Comment: I ran into memory issues with my dictionary method, when I was approaching 16 million elements.. glad it was useful :-)

Comment: Hi Peroxy, thank you for the detail explanation ! Your answer seems to cover all the posible nice implementations.

Comment: It is nice, but OP stated "Only the consecutive equal numbers will be grouped." Your two solutions give different results.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek is right, my solution is not correct, if the consecutive equal numbers are only supposed to be grouped, I did not see that initially.. you should refer to Ivan Stoev's answer.

Comment: Yes, that's true I was not so clear about that case, that the equal numbers has to be next to each other in order to be grouped. Any way nice examples Peroxy for those other cases.